# Hipster auf deutsch

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Sagt man im Deutschen auch "Hipster" oder gibt es ein passendes deutsches Wort?

Ich dachte erst an "Schickimicki", aber das passt nicht ganz, weil es sich nach meinem Verständnis auf Mode, Luxus und gesellschaftliche Stellung bezieht, nicht auf "Ich hab den Trend gemacht, als ihn noch keiner kannte".

Wenn man im Deutschen auch Hipster sagt, was ist die weibliche Form davon? Auch Hipster? Hipsterin?

Comment: "Hipster" heitßt auf Deutsch "Hiptster", ganz klar.

Comment: Ganz generell kann man sagen: Wenn etwas neues entsteht, das sowohl im englischen als auch im deutschen Sprachraum Verbreitung findet, und wenn sich dafür im englischen Sprachraum eine Bezeichnung etabliert, dann wird diese Bezeichnung als Lehnwort in den deutschen Wortschatz integriert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aus meiner Erfahrung heraus (ich kann die ganze Bewegung leider weder nachvollziehen noch leiden :D) werden die im deutschen auch als Hipster bezeichnet.

Answer (score 5):

Ein Punk ist auch im Deutschen ein Punk.
Ein Hippie ist auch im Deutschen ein Hippie.
Ein Beatnik ist auch im Deutschen ein Beatnik
Ein Skinhead ist auch im Deutschen ein Skinhead.

Ein Hipster ist auch im Deutschen ein Hipster.

Bezeichnungen für Subkulturen werden nicht übersetzt.

---

Eine weibliche Form gibt es zum Hipster ebensowenig wie zum Skinhead, Punk oder Hippie.

---

"Schickimicki" ist ein Begriff, der in den 80ern aufkam und Anfang der 90er seinen Verbreitungshöhepunkt fand. Seither geht die Verwendung wieder zurück. (Siehe https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schickimicki&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSchickimicki%3B%2Cc0) So ein Begriff ist an eine bestimmte Zeit gebunden und bedeutet, anders als im Duden dargestellt, nicht allgemein "jemand[en], der sich betont modisch gibt", sondern jemanden, der in der großstädtischen Clubszene im Deutschland der 80er Jahre unterwegs ist und dabei die Boulevard-Stars und den Geldadel der Zeit im Look nachahmt. Diese gesamte Kultur existiert heute nicht mehr, deshalb ist der Begriff auch für heutige Phänomene unpassend, insbesondere für solche außerhalb Deutschlands.

Answer (score 3):

[zur zweiten Frage:](http://www.sprachlog.de/2013/01/29/hipster-anglizismus-2012/?fb_source=pubv1)

> Hipster liegt fürs Deutsche — vermutlich — ausnahmslos als Maskulinum
>   vor. Versuche, nach femininen Formen zu suchen, sind zum Scheitern
>   verurteilt, weil für Hipster die meisten Genus-, Kasus– und
>   Numeruskombinationen zusammenfallen und Suchergebnisse deshalb nicht
>   auseinanderzuhalten, geschweigedenn vergleichbar sind (die Hipster für
>   FEM.SG,  MASK.PL und MASK.PL„generisch“, etc.). Der Hipster hat mit
>   gerundet 39,000 Treffern gegenüber die Hipsterin mit 224 Treffern
>   leicht die Nase vorn. Es ist unwahrscheinlich, dass hier 38,776 Fälle
>   von Synkretismus vorliegen. Wahrscheinlicher ist, dass Hipster, obwohl
>   genderbar, nicht gegendert wird. Abgeleitet von Hipster gibt es erste
>   Versuche, hipstern als Verb zu etablieren.

Answer (score 0):

"Hipster" heitßt auf Deutsch "Hiptster", ganz klar.

Eine weibliche Form gibt es nicht, wobei jede verstehen würde, wenn man von "Hipstertusse" sprechen würde :)
(wäre aber nicht besonders nett)